# Horner rule product form order

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to show the ordering of the Horner rule product form. Here is a definition for ordering The notation $O$ (which stands for order) for a function $f$ is derived by the following simplification rules:

If $f(x)$ is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth is kept, and all others omitted.

If $f(x)$ is a product of several factors, any constants are omitted.

If the roots of the polynomial are known we can use a recurrence based on $$p_n(x) = \alpha_n(x - p_1)\ldots(x-p_n)$$
given by:

$d_0 = \alpha_n$

for $i = 1:n$

$d_i = d_{i-1}(x - p_i)$

end

$p_n(x) = d_n$

I believe it is of order $O(n^2)$ but I am not sure how to show this. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand the question. Are you trying to evaluate a polynomial using Horner's rule and asking how long will that take

Comment: No, I am asking what is the order of the algorithm. As in the computations required to achieve the result. This is known as Big $O$ notation.

Comment: Order of the algorithm to do what -- to evaluate a polynomial using Horner's rule?

Comment: Yes, but this type of algorithm is Horner rule product form

Comment: Actually and literally, there is no Horner (or Ruffini) scheme. The idea of the nested evaluation can be traced back to Newton and is, quite loosely, attributed to Lagrange in the Horner paper that discusses a Newton-like method for manually finding polynomial roots. Thus a Horner-rule for the product of linear factors seems to be an even greater misnomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating a polynomial using Horner's rule involves rewriting it, e.g. as follows:
$$
p(x) = 3x^3+4x^2+5x+6 = 6 + x(5 + x(4 + 3x)),
$$
and then evaluating it at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ takes $n$ multiplications and $n$ additions, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. This would be $O(n)$ then.

For the product form of Horner's rule, which is described in the question, you have a loop with $n$ iterations, making one assignment, one subtraction and one multiplication, i.e. a constant cost per iteration. This would make it $O(n)$ as well...

Comment: Correct, but this is not the product form of Horner rule

Comment: @MorganWeiss see update

Comment: thanks, if you know this stuff well check out my earlier post. I am not sure how to completely prove it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436860/backward-stability-bound

Comment: @MorganWeiss looked but don't have that much time now, maybe in a day or two will look again

Comment: Ok, thank you very much